# How to clear page and component caching by a URL in Joomla 2.5.x?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

There is a website made in Joomla 2.5.x. It has System Cache enabled. The website contains a component called **com_magic** that handles URLS like:

```
https://websiteurl.com/bikes?view=best
https://websiteurl.com/bikes?view=latest
```

System Cache timeout is set globally to 7 days. But the problem is with latest view. Each day a cron job fetched data from bike provider endpoint. It checks if there are new bikes. And if yes, it adds them to the database.

Unfortunately since system cache is set to 7 days, if a new bike occurs, the latest url does not display new bikes until the cache gets invalidated.

The cache for both page and component com_magic should be therefore cleared:

1. Each day or
2. When new bike becomes available

For URL:

```
https://websiteurl.com/bikes?view=latest
```

- How to clear cache for above URL both for page cache and com_magic
  component cache programatically? Or:
- How to change cache timeout for page and com_magic component for this URL to 1 day specifically? Or:
- How to disable caching for this particular URL for page and com_magic component?

*Important note: This is a question about backend Joomla cache. NOT about browser cache!*

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: Either modify the cron to also clear the cache (using the joomla api) or run a second cron job to do that.

Comment: @Elin The question is how to clear cache for this page only. I can not clear 10 GB of cache every day because it would be a performance kill. Prewarming of 10GB of cache is also not an option (too long to generate)

Comment: Yes and? Did you read the api for clearing cache?

Comment: @Elin Yes. I have read it. Why are you asking?